# Ajax JSON PHP Stringify not posting but returning successfully

Tags: php, ajax, json, stringify

I have an ajax script of which gatheres values from inputs and then inserts to a mysql database using `MYSQLI`.

When i click the button the unique id is returned successfully but none of the post values are being inserted into the database. Also when testing the post values individually they too do not show as reaching the posted php script.

After running this the unique id is in the database but no other information is stored.

`Q. How come the variables not reaching the PHP, thus preventing me from a successful insertion to the database?`

The Ajax

```
$('#postData').click(function() {
        smallVan_getForm_values();

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "//xxxxx",
     data: JSON.stringify({
            book_email:book_email,
            book_clientTitle : book_clientTitle,
            book_firstname : book_firstname,
            book_lastname :book_lastname,
            book_dateofbirth : book_dateofbirth,
            book_primarycontactnumber : book_primarycontactnumber,
            book_secondarycontactnumber : book_secondarycontactnumber,
            departing_first_lineaddress : departing_first_lineaddress,
            departing_second_lineaddress : departing_second_lineaddress,
            departing_postcode : departing_postcode,
            destination_first_lineaddress : destination_first_lineaddress,
            destination_second_lineaddress : destination_second_lineaddress,
            destination_postcode : destination_postcode,
            amount : amount,
            book_consignmentdate : book_consignmentdate,
            book_timeofbooking : book_timeofbooking,
            book_additionalnotes : book_additionalnotes
    }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (result) {
        //  alert(result);

            if (result.status == "success"){
                    uniqueID = result.uniqueID;
                    alert(uniqueID);

            }

       }
    });

});

});
//AJAX END
```

**The PHP**

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{ //if request made from localserver then proceed here
    insertData();
}


function insertData() {

$uniqueID = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ", 10)), 0, 10);


    $conn=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxxxx^","xxxxx");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // Perform queries
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO bookings_table ( booking_uniqueID , book_email , book_clientTitle , book_firstname , book_lastname , book_dateofbirth , book_primarycontactnumber , book_secondarycontactnumber , departing_first_lineaddress , departing_second_lineaddress , departing_postcode , destination_first_lineaddress , destination_second_lineaddress , destination_postcode , amount , book_consignmentdate , book_timeofbooking , book_additionalnotes )
   VALUES ( '$uniqueID' , '$_POST[book_email]' , '$_POST[book_clientTitle]' , '$_POST[book_firstname]' , '$_POST[book_lastname]' , '$_POST[book_dateofbirth]' , '$_POST[book_primarycontactnumber]' , '$_POST[book_secondarycontactnumber]' , '$_POST[departing_first_lineaddress]' , '$_POST[departing_second_lineaddress]' , '$_POST[departing_postcode]' , '$_POST[destination_first_lineaddress]' , '$_POST[destination_second_lineaddress]' , '$_POST[destination_postcode]' , '$_POST[amount]' , '$_POST[book_consignmentdate]' , '$_POST[book_timeofbooking]' , '$_POST[book_additionalnotes]' )");

    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'uniqueID' => $uniqueID));

}
```

Comment: If you're getting the `uniqueID` back, then clearly `mysqli_query` is being called. What value is `mysqli_query` returning?

Comment: i am getting the uniqueID back yes. But the posted data did not get inserted as it doesnt appear to be posting to the sql. The sql is inserting only the uniqueID becuase that appears all to be there. Tested this with posting the vars at the php page, they are not reaching the php page via that ajax.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Glad to see that someone else understood it though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove your JSON.stringify().

```
data: {
            book_email:book_email,
            book_clientTitle : book_clientTitle,
            book_firstname : book_firstname,
            book_lastname :book_lastname,
            book_dateofbirth : book_dateofbirth,
            book_primarycontactnumber : book_primarycontactnumber,
            book_secondarycontactnumber : book_secondarycontactnumber,
            departing_first_lineaddress : departing_first_lineaddress,
            departing_second_lineaddress : departing_second_lineaddress,
            departing_postcode : departing_postcode,
            destination_first_lineaddress : destination_first_lineaddress,
            destination_second_lineaddress : destination_second_lineaddress,
            destination_postcode : destination_postcode,
            amount : amount,
            book_consignmentdate : book_consignmentdate,
            book_timeofbooking : book_timeofbooking,
            book_additionalnotes : book_additionalnotes
    },
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not insert anything.

Comment: when i test this with a simple POST ajax they are all returning correctly, its when i begin to use the json that they do not.

Comment: i just trying your code with some post parameters, and i remove `JSON.stringify()` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, its worked. 
your data was formated in JSON, your parameter dataType was set to `JSON` before. and contentType default encoding is `charset=utf-8`, so i remove it.

Comment: I missed to take out `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` it now works, ok thank you so much!